# Connect Phone by USB Creates Open/Close Loop

Tags: usb, nautilus, 18.04, transfer

I'm trying to transfer some files from my cell to my laptop. the Bluetooth is being a pain and keeps stalling and failing, so I'm trying the USB cable. That's being a problem too. I choose on my phone to transfer files, and then Nautilus just keeps opening it and closing it over and over and seems stuck in a loop. What's going on & how do I stop that? I just want to plug it in & transfer the files. I tried rebooting a couple times and trying the process again, but that doesn't work.

Device: Pixel 2 XL

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install libmtp and libmtp9, but Ubuntu says it is already the newest version, so all of these did not work for me

But android-file-transfer worked for me for Ubuntu 18.04 lts version and Samsung android version 5.1.1

**Install android-file transfer:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer
```